# Using Moment.js to check if date is over x number of years from now

Tags: javascript, datatables, momentjs

I need to check whether a date I have is over X number of years ago from today.

For example, if 2018-01-01 is over 3 years ago from now, colour it amber, else if it is over 4 years ago from now, colour it red.

So far, I've just used `diff()` but this isn't really what I need.

```
var difference = moment(data.purchase_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  .month(0)
  .from(moment().month(0));

if (difference === '3 years ago') {
  $('td:eq(5)', row).addClass('bgc-orange-50');
} else if (difference === '4 years ago') {
  $('td:eq(5)', row).addClass('bgc-red-50');
}
```

Comment: How granular a difference do you need? For example, is 2018-01-01 three or four years after 2014-12-31?

Answer (score 2):

I've worked it out.

```
    var purchase_date = moment(data.purchase_date, "YYYY-MM-DD");
    var now = moment();

    var difference = now.diff(purchase_date, 'days');
```

Then do an `if` statement to check the days are greater than 1095 but less than 1460 etc.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = moment("2015-05-05", "YYYY") // year in your date
var b = moment(new Date(), "YYYY") // current year

var yearCountDiff = b.diff(a, 'year')
console.log(yearCountDiff)

if (yearCountDiff === 3) {
  console.log('3 years')
  // $("td:eq(5)", row).addClass("bgc-orange-50");
} else if (yearCountDiff === 4) {
  console.log('4 years')
  // $("td:eq(5)", row).addClass("bgc-red-50");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```